# Rational root of the sum of two squares

Tags: calculus, number-theory, proof-verification, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I am a freshman in highschool interested in math. Please don't judge me if the answer is either obvious or obviously doesn't exist.

Let $x$ and $y$ be rational numbers

$$x^2 + y^2 = z$$
$\sqrt z$ = rational number

Q: Are there numbers that would satisfy these equations?

Comment: Did you even try to find any ? If there are rational solutions, then there are integer ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x=3$ and $y=4$, then $\sqrt{z}=5$. Moreover, for any positive integers $p$ and $q$, if $x= \frac{3p}{q}$ and $y= \frac{4p}{q}$, then $\sqrt{z} = \frac{5p}{q}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Deep down I knew it was a dumb question:)

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Pythagorean triples...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple